# Selenium Webdriver :How I can skip failed Step & continue to next step

Tags: c#, selenium

My Scenarios is as follows:

I have 5 buttons/links in Upper Menu. And I want to visit each page by clicking on them and want to make sure whether page contents Loaded/Appears properly or NOT. So, to do that I did the following:

**Step 1:**

```
:Browser:   :Search:    :Compare:   :Contact Us:
```

**Step 2:**

```
 a. I click on 'Browse Page'
 b. After load the Browse Page, I Capture/Get the Header Text
 c. Then I Use IF ELSE to check whether Header Text is matched with my text or not
 d. If header text matched, I write "PASS" in Console
 f. If header text didn't match, I write "FAIL" in Console
```

**Step 3:**

a.
 b.
 ...

**My Problem :**
if Somehow My Page not loaded properly or Crash, and my code Can't Capture the Header text by FindElements(By.XPath) or others. then My Selenium Code STOP working.

So, I want in this case, if It can't find the Page header for Crash or other reason... it will JUMP to NEXT STEP to check other pages.

```
IWebElement Menu_Browse = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/a"));
    Menu_Browse.Click();//Goto Browse page

if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/h3")).Displayed)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS! - BROWSE Page Appears Properly without any CRASH!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FAIL! - BROWSE Page may be CRASH! -- JUMP to Next Step of Testing!!");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 5 elements are independent (I suppose they are based on your description), just write 5 tests instead of writing a big one to test everything. This way, you can detect independent failures, and it minimizes units of code.

If you really want to jump, you can either :
-Use non failing methods, here you could consider findElements instead of findElement, and then test the count of elements returned by this method.
-Try catch the line throwing an exception and manually handling this case (note that it's commonly seen has a bad practice to catch exception as part of the acceptable workflow).

Comment: Thanks! for the Suggestion to breakdown the code into pieces.

But I really want to know how to JUMP next step if some step fail for Not loading the page or crashing the page. Interested to learn this part of code. I tried as follows:

if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/h3")).Displayed)

But it's not working.

Comment: Edited answer with what you may need

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `Boolean` value of `Element` in a variable whether it is displayed of not, and then write an **if condition** for that particular value.

```
If true 
 (ur code)
If false
 (ur code)
```